# image that is inside of a div is showing up 1 px lower then the expected height?

Tags: html, css, image, height

I am currently trying to create a "web app", (which for me, just means a website that works on many different browser sizes atm..) that has a list of "buttons" in such a way that you can scroll through them and click on them as needed. All I am currently trying to accomplish is have each "button" or "row" have wording on the left, and an arrow on the right. (if this doesn't make sense, I have linked to a zip of the current site)
the way I currently have it layed out is that there are 2 containers (div) for each row, 1 for the left side with text, (which has the text aligned to the left (with a slight padding)) and 1 for the right (which has the image (arrow) aligned to the right (also with slight padding)).
the problem is that when I view the page, the arrow image is located 1 px below the height of the rest of the div, (which has a bg img, jsyk) causing it to show a scroll wheel.
I can't find any way to fix it yet, any ideas?

Link to site download:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/268789013/ios_app_test.zip

Comment: A jsfiddle or similar would be nice :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include your relevant code (HTML, CSS, etc) in your question. If possible, try to reproduce the problem in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
overflow: hidden;
```

on the div that contains your arrow.